# IndexError: list index out of range vk api

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Имеем этот код, выбивает ошибку

Как починить?

*delete = popa["items"][0]["id"]*

*IndexError: list index out of range*

````
import vk_api
import random
import time
vk = vk_api.VkApi(token="")
vk2 = vk_api.VkApi(token="")
b = random.randint(1, 100)
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods = ["POST"])
def main():
    data = json.loads(request.data)
    if data["type"] == "confirmation":
        return "f23f35f8"
    elif data["type"] == "message_new":
        object = data["object"]
        id = object["peer_id"]
        delete = object["from_id"]
        body = object["text"]
        msgid = object["conversation_message_id"]

        if delete == 472165736:
                popa = vk2.method("messages.getByConversationMessageId", {"peer_id": id, "conversation_message_ids": msgid })
                delete = popa["items"][0]["id"]
                vk2.method("messages.delete", {"peer_id": id,"message_ids": delete, "delete_for_all": 1})

        if body.lower() == "reevo restart":

                vk.method("messages.send", {"peer_id": id, "message": "ReEvo 0.17.0(podPivas)  started,\n  created by @tripl_color @neoncrusaider - лох \n А КАК СВЯЗАЦА С БАРДЮРАМ У МИНЯ ПОД СЛОМАЛСЯ", "random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})



######################################################################################################  WARN BODY #############################################################################################################


       









############################################################################################### BAN BODY ####################################################################################################################################




############################################################################################### MUTE BODY ####################################################################################################################################






        elif body.lower() == "я - гуль":
                vk.method("messages.send", {"peer_id": id, "message": "ух ты, гуль", "random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})
        else:
            time.sleep(1)
    return "ok"```
````

Answer (score 0):

Индекс вне границ массива. Распечатайте вашу переменную «popa» и проверьте, правильно ли вы пытаетесь получить переменную “id” и оттуда ли вы пытаетесь ее «выцепить».

Скорее всего, именно в этом ошибка: ["items"][0]["id"], возможно вам также стоит заполнить определённые fields.  [Ознакомьтесь тут: документация по данному методу](https://dev.vk.com/method/messages.getByConversationMessageId)